# Identifying if a project is active from start and end date or active in current month in Excel

Tags: excel, date

I have a simple spreadsheet to track projects that are currently ongoing, with two columns containing a date – one is the project start date, and the other is the project end date.

I have a further two columns to enable me to produce reports of projects that are currently active, or have been active during the current month. For the column for projects that have been active during the current month I’m using this formula:

```
=IF(OR(MONTH(H5)=MONTH(TODAY()),MONTH(I5)=MONTH(TODAY())),"Yes","No")
```

This picks up projects that have a start or end date in the current month, but not those that have a start date but no end date, meaning that the project’s ongoing. I’ve tried this formula, amongst various variations, which I thought should work:

```
=IF(OR(MONTH(H5)=MONTH(TODAY()),MONTH(I5)=MONTH(TODAY()),(ISBLANK(I5))),"Yes","No")
```

…but this just returns “No” for every row. I know I need a formula that tests if the date in either column is in the current month, or if the start date is in the current month but the end date is blank, but I just can’t figure out what the formula is.

Similarly, I have another column that shows whether a project is currently active, and I’m using this formula to test whether today’s date is between the dates in the start date and end date columns:

```
=IF(AND(TODAY()>=H5,TODAY()<=I5),"Current","Closed")
```

Again, this works fine as long as there’s a date in both columns, but if the end date is blank, again meaning that the project’s ongoing, it returns “closed” when it should be returning “current”, and again I can’t figure out the right formula.

The nearest I’ve tried that gives a result (but not the result I want) is:

```
=IF(AND(TODAY()>=H5,TODAY()<=I5)*OR($H5<TODAY(),$I5=""),"Current","Closed")
```

…but again it only picks up where there are dates in both columns, and if the end date is after today’s date but not blank.

I’m sure I’m probably missing something blindingly obvious, but I can’t figure it out. Any guidance appreciated.

Edit: Also, if both the start date and end date are empty, the 'currently active' and 'active this month' cells should remain blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last one is nearly OK, but you need to test

```
    (1A) Start date on or before today
    AND
    (1B) Start date not blank
AND
    (2A) End date on or after today 
    OR
    (2B) End date blank.
```

leading to

```
=IF(AND(AND(TODAY()>=H2,H2<>""),OR(TODAY()<=I2,$I2="")),"Current","Closed")
```

To see if the project is active in the current month, I would use the standard overlap formula for two time periods, but first testing to see if the start date is blank (in which case set the result to blank):

```
=IF(H2="","",IF(MIN(I2,EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))>=MAX(H2,EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1),"Current","Not Current"))
```

If I2 is blank, the MIN function will ignore it so the formula will just test to see if the start date in H2 is in or after the current month.

Comment: Thank you - that works great! The only problem is that if there are blank rows and both H5 and I5 are blank, it still returns "current". I've tried: `=IF(AND(TODAY()>=H5,OR(TODAY()<=I5,I5="",OR(ISBLANK(H5:I5),""),"Current","Closed")` but Excel says I'm missing a parenthesis and I can't see where.

Comment: I've now also figured out what was wrong with the other formula that tests whether a project has been active in the current month - it was an identical problem, missing `I5=""`. This formula works: `=IF(OR(MONTH(H5)=MONTH(TODAY()),MONTH(I5)=MONTH(TODAY()),OR(I5="")),"Yes","No")` , but has the same problem that if there are blank rows and for example both the cells in column H and column I are empty, it still returns "Yes".

Comment: I've got the formula for currently active projects:
`=IF(AND(H5="",I5=""),"",IF(AND(TODAY()>=H5,OR(TODAY()<=I5,I5="")),"Current","Closed"))`
My only problem now is the formula for checking if the project's been active in the current month. This formula:
`=IF(AND(H5="",I5=""),"",IF(OR(MONTH(H5)=MONTH(TODAY()),MONTH(I5)=MONTH(TODAY()),OR(I5="")),"Yes","No"))`
works but returns "Yes" for dates occurring in any March. This is my latest try:
`IF(AND(H5="",I5=""),"",(OR(MONTH(H5)&YEAR(H5)=MONTH(TODAY())&YEAR(TODAY()),OR(MONTH(I5)&YEAR(I5)=MONTH(TODAY())&YEAR(TODAY())),OR(I5="")),"Yes","No"))`

Comment: Sorry, just catching  up with this. I will add the condition to report it as 'closed' if both H2 & I2 are blank, then look at projects active any time in the current month.

Comment: You're testing for a project that either begins or ends in the current month. What if it spans the current month, e.g. it begins in February 2018 and ends in April 2018? Then you need to check for a start date on/before March 31st and an end date on/after March 1st with the added condition on blank dates and always assuming the dates are in the correct order.

Comment: You're right - I didn't consider that situation. With the test dates I've put in, it is picking up a project with a start date in February 2018 but no end date, I guess because of the condition to check if the end date's empty rather than because it's checking for a start date that's potentially before the start of the month.

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly. I had eventually figured out that EOMONTH was probably the easiest way to do it following your last comment. I was trying to do it using `H5<=EOMONTH(H5,0)` and `I5>=EOMONTH(I5,-1)+1` but ccouldn't get the formula right. Yours works perfectly though. Thanks again.